# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NASCell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Pretty much self-explanatory: I would like to use the [NASCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/NASCell) in my RNN model, however this line:

```
nas_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.NASCell(n_input)
```

throws:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NASCell'
```

Where is `NASCell` located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the newset version of `tensorflow`?
According to [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/1e982bb8330c0c5a571559e8653c5e8b948a621e) `NASCell` was added on **15 Feb**, so you could have older version of tensor flow.

Comment: I have tensorflow version 1.0.1

Comment: @dv3 I just downloaded **v1.0.1** and there isn't `NASCell` class - according to commit I referred to in original answer, this class is tagged for newest version **v1.1.0-rc0**. You won't be able to use it unless you upgrade.

Comment: ah that makes sense :) thx! I installed tf via pip - do you know if there's a way to point pip to the 1.1 branch? Or do I need to build it from source?

Comment: @dv3 Try this: `pip3 install -e git://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git.git@v1.1.0-rc0#egg=tensorflow` I will check if this works when I'm home. Could you mark my response as answer?

Comment: sure - It's quite strange that my pip doesn't find the newest version..  with the direct link to 1.1 it works but shouldnt it find it by itself..

Comment: @dv3 **v1.1.0-rc0** rc in this version name means **R**elease **C**andidate, so something more advanced than **beta** version, but still not production quality - maybe they lack some minor features.